# Different IP for each bot?

Tags: python, web, ip, bots, proxies

I'm doing a Python bot that will request an url under different IP addresses in one computer. Is there a way to change my IP address for free and apply it to the bot? I have looked around and it seems like people say that I should use proxies for this. But I'm not familiar with proxies and how to implement them in Python. It'd be great if someone can guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your IP in python, but your gateway will not be able to route a different IP than one in your sub-net.
Therefore, you have to use a proxy or a diffente router.

If you have/know an active router that will forward your packages using NAT, you can it as the gateway for the IP of the URL you are going to request.

For changing routes you can use this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroute2

For using proxies directly in your bot, assuming you are using urllib3, you can check this documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/.

Another thing you might do is to rent some VPS servers for different worldwide IPs, check this [search](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vps%20hosting) for examples.

Comment: It seems like proxies will be the best solution in my situation since I need around 100 different IPs and don't want to pay for VPS servers nor look for 100 active routers. However, I'm still having a trouble understanding how proxies will securely hide your IP simply because you connect to a proxy with a unique IP and use the proxy's IP to connect to certain url. So no matter what, they still can know and actually track your real IP. Is my logic right or totally wrong?

Comment: Yes, if the proxy logs all access, they can track your IP back. If you want anonymity, you can use TOR as the first route out, and from it connect to the proxies.